# object detection loss

Tags: overfitting, train, object-detection

I have trained an ssd detector in my own dataset and the values of train loss and val loss are shown in the picture. However in all the epochs the value of val loss is lower than that of train loss ? Is it wrong ?[image]

Comment: Are you sure your train/val sets are mutually disjoint? i.e., there's no overlap in them?

Comment: yes .they can have overlap.  the dataset is Udacity dataset and I think some pictures have same objects .there are frames of road object detection movies .